# rospy tf waitForTransform not waiting

Tags: rospy, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I keep getting lookup extrapolation errors when trying to use tf, even when using listener.waitForTransform. For example I get:

Exception: Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time 1428875486.097693682 but the latest data is at time 1428875486.097676516, when looking up transform from frame [ugv0] to frame [image]

The difference in time is less than a millisecond, and even if my timeout duration is very long, I still get an extrapolation error. My code has:

tfl.waitForTransform('image',obj_name,timeStamp,rospy.Duration(10.0))

The tf call is in a callback on a topic that has data published to it at a very fast rate, approximately 360hz, and the relevant transforms are also all being published at ~360hz except for a static transform, which is at 10hz. I would attach the pdf of the view frames output, but I dont have enough points to attach files.

What is wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207052/rospy-tf-waitfortransform-not-waiting/) by [anuppari](https://answers.ros.org/users/5082/anuppari/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2015-04-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a ticket [here](https://github.com/ros/geometry_experimental/issues/102) tracking this issue.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0